# Плавное изменение бэкграунда блока

Tags: jquery, изображения, slider

На странице есть слайдер, в котором крутится несколько картинок.
В слайдере определяется текущая картинка, из нее берется data-параметр и подставляется в качестве бэкграунда для блока.

```
slideItems.removeClass('current');
slideItems.eq(currentSlide).addClass('current');
var current_image_src = $('.carousel .slideItem.current img').data('bg-image-src');
$('.conteiner').css('background-image', 'url(http:' + current_image_src + ')');
```

Но при таком варианте картинка меняется резко.
Как можно сделать так, чтобы картинка менялась плавно с использованием `animate()`?

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать вот так:

1. http://jsfiddle.net/8su9hpcs/
2. http://jsfiddle.net/8su9hpcs/4/

Comment: Да, такой вариант у меня был, но то, что бэграунд полностью исчезает, а потом снова появляется, уже новый, не подходит. Пока сделано просто с помощью добавления свойства `.transition(1s)` к блоку, работает, дальше, возможно, придется все-таки что-то придумывать на jQuery через animate() opacity.

Comment: Добавил 2-й вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Background-image поддаётся анимации при помощи css3 transitions:

```
.conteiner {transition: background-image 0.3s;}
```

При помощи animate вы сможете выполнить похожую анимацию, только если меняться будет не background, а изображения img.

Могу посоветовать в качестве анимационного движка TweenMax. Он, по-моему, умеет анимировать в том числе и background-image.

Comment: Да, у меня пока и сделано через `transition`.